# Laravel: get children by parent slug

Tags: laravel-5

I have a Section and a Picture models, with a one-to-many relationship (Section can have many Pictures; Picture has only one Section)

I'm able to retrieve all Pictures given a Section id:

```
$section = '1';
$records = Picture::where('section_id', $section)->orderBy('position')->get();
```

What if I'd like to retrieve Picture by Section slug (or name)?
All these examples don't work:

```
$section = 'wedding';
$records = Picture::where('sections.slug', $section)->orderBy('position')->get(); // nope
$records = Picture::where($this->section()->slug, $section)->orderBy('position')->get(); // nope
```

I tried to search in Laravel docs, but I didn't get the case...
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For querying relations you should use [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) function.

If your relation is named `section()` in `Picture` model then your query should be as:

```
$section = 'wedding';

$records = Picture::whereHas('section', function($q) use($section) {
                            $q->where('slug', $section);
                        })
                        ->orderBy('position')
                        ->get();
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a little bit more "immediate"... thanks though, this works!